# Is there a way to find all of the separate forces (as b2Vec2's) acting on a body at a given time?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, box2d, physics-engine

I'm new to Box2D, (and actionscript in general) and I'm making a sort of a teaching tool for physics students. I'm trying to be able to display the forces (as vectors) acting at a body at a given moment in time. Is there a method of finding the separate vectors acting on a body (e.g. friction, normal force, gravity etc.) and having them available to work with? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an easy way, no. There is a PostSolve function which lets you get the impulses that were applied to two bodies to push them apart when they overlap, and this has a normal and tangent (friction I guess) component. From these you could come up with something close to what you're talking about.

Something to consider if you're to be teaching with this is that many corners are cut in the interest of keeping the library efficient, eg. friction is not accurate, the normal is not always what might be expected. You might find this interesting: http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-anatomy

Comment: This is incredibly helpful! Thank you.

Comment: Would there be a way to find the _net_ force acting on an object at a given moment?